# IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed

Tags: android, cursor, listadapter

```
int columnIndexFromAddrCountry;

public FavoritesActAdapter(Context context, int layout, 
        Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    gnCursor = c;

    columnIndexFromAddrCountry = 
        c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_FROM_ADDR_COUNTRY);

}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    gnCursor = getCursor();

    final String fromAddrCountry = 
        gnCursor.getString(columnIndexFromAddrCountry);

        ...

        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
}
```

Why am I getting an `IllegalStateException`?

> IllegalStateException: get field slot
>   from row 0 col -1 failed

What does this Exception mean? The Exception is thrown for this line

```
final String fromAddrCountry = gnCursor.getString(columnIndexFromAddrCountry);
```

because `columnIndexFromAddrCountry` is `-1`.
The column exists and ten other columns can be resolved. What can causes this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `DBAdapter.KEY_FROM_ADDR_COUNTRY` set to?

From the [Cursor doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)

> public abstract int getColumnIndex
>   (String columnName)
>
> Since: API Level 1 Returns the
>   zero-based index for the given column
>   name, or -1 if the column doesn't
>   exist. If you expect the column to
>   exist use
>   getColumnIndexOrThrow(String) instead,
>   which will make the error more clear

So you can use the `getColumnIndexOrThrow(String)` to have a better error message that will help you debugging.

Comment: `DBAdapter.KEY_FROM_ADDR_COUNTRY` is a public static String, which represents the name of the column. The same String is used to create the table.

Comment: Ok, then you can make sure that the cursor is from a query on the table where the `KEY_FROM_ADDR_COUNTRY` belongs to.

Comment: Yeah! Your hint was not completely right, but almost. ;) The cursor is handed over correctly and was on the correct table. But: I receive the cursor by calling a query on my database. Within this query I had twice the same column (which is very similary to the KEY_FROM_ADDR_COUNTRY). Stupid mistake... ^^ Thanks!